# How to apply a css for a grid called from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, gridview

I am using a javascript function for print option to print a gridview.

**JS**:

```
 function PrintGridData() {
      var prtGrid = document.getElementById('<%=gvUserInfo.ClientID %>');
      prtGrid.border = 0;
      var prtwin = window.open('', 'PrintGridViewData', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,tollbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
      prtwin.document.write(prtGrid.outerHTML);
      prtwin.document.close();
      prtwin.focus();
      prtwin.print();
      prtwin.close();
    }
```

works fine..

But "gvUserInfo" gridview has no borders and no grids(thats the css applied) but in the print page I want the border and gridlines..
now how to apply border and gridlines in the print page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include the style sheet that applies the styles you are missing. Either do that, or find a library that can apply styles as style attributes before you copy in the outerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add This in first line of javascript.

```
document.getElementById('<%= gvUserInfo.ClientID %>').className = "class";
```